# Install Drivers to show up in device manager

Tags: command-line, installation, driver

I have some unsigned drivers that I have written myself.  I can install my drivers through device manager by adding legacy hardware and the driver installs just fine and shows up in device manager.

I want to be able to install the driver through some command line or script, however both dpinst.exe and installhinfsection only install the driver software first, meaning it doesn't actually install on your computer until you plug in the device.  I would like a way to install the driver automatically and have it show up in device manager as an install driver.

Any help would be great,
Thanks in advance